# Transfer data from old Windows 7 laptop to new Windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, laptop

I am looking to transfer my data from old Windows 7 laptop to new Windows 10 laptop. My preferred option would be over Wifi, as both the laptops are connected to the same Home Wifi.

I have been trying to have both the laptops over the Network, but not able to do so for the new Windows 10 laptop.

Any suggestions/steps would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you local accounts on both computers, or is the one on Windows 10 a Microsoft account?

Comment: Not 100% sure....But I think the Windows 10 seems Microsoft account...Remember giving pwd for Microsoft a/c during initial laptop setup...But Windows 7 is 100% sure local a/c

Comment: It would be simpler to [re-enable the SMBv1 protocol on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-access-files-network-devices-using-smbv1-windows-10).(Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc - Thanks a lot...So, I just verified that SMB 1.0/CIFS Client option is alreadt checked/enabled on my Windows 10 laptop

Comment: However...running this command returned true;  Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB1Protocol

Comment: though I got an error (Set-SmbServerConfiguration : The specified service does not exist.) while trying to enable via this command; Set-SmbServerConfiguration –EnableSMB1Protocol $true

Comment: @harrymc - Also, I was on Windows account (seems like this is the default option now during initial setup) , but have again switched back to local account now...

Comment: Did you verify SMBv1 after a reboot?

Comment: @harrymc - I enabled SMBv1 via some different command on my Windows 10 laptop and did reboot...but still not able to do file share...

Comment: If SMBv1 is enabled and Windows 10 is on local account and both computers are on WORKGROUP and can ping each other, and the share is created with maximal permissions on both the share and the underlying folder, then there is no reason for them not to be able to share.

Comment: @harrymc - 1. Just as a confirmation - if you can let me know, how to quickly validate using Command to check if SMBv1 is enabled. I can run and send you the result.
2. Regarding ping, I tried doing that ping 192.168.0.x using the IPv4 (Preferred) address and both the laptops are unable to do that. Firewall issue? Pls let me know what I should check there

Comment: If the computers cannot ping each other then they cannot share. You may try temporarily try to disable all firewalls and to verify the router and the properties of the network adapters on the computers. As long as you can't ping then you have a problem.

Comment: So after turning off the firewall on both, I can ping each other...But still do not see the laptops under Network for both of them !

Comment: Again just as a confirmation - if you can let me know, how to quickly validate using Command to check if SMBv1 is enabled. I can run and send you the result.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following steps on each machine to enable File Sharing.

**(1)** Make sure SMBv2 was not disabled in Windows 7 . Disable SMBv1

[SMBv2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3)

**(2)** Follow the section in the article:

> For Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista, and Windows
> Server 2008 To enable or disable SMB protocols on an SMB Server that
> is running Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista, or
> Windows Server 2008, use Windows PowerShell or Registry Editor.
>
> Get-Item
> HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters |
> ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath}
>
> Default configuration = Enabled (No registry key is created), so no
> SMB1 value will be returned

Another article to try (there are a number because the change from Windows 7 to newer Windows 10 is quite great) is here.

[Another SMBv2 article](https://kb.bodhost.com/steps-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-servers/)

> Set-ItemProperty -Path
> “HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters” SMB2
> -Value 1 -Force

**(3)** Make sure Network Discovery, File and Print Sharing and Password Protected Sharing are all ON for both machines.

**(4)** Make sure Home Group in Windows 7 has been turned off. Home Group was deprecated in Windows 10 and is gone.

**(5)** Make sure both computers are in WORKGROUP. Computer Properties, Name.

Here is a screen shot of changing WORKGROUP. Depending on the Windows 10 version, right click on My Computer (Computer), select Properties and in the Window that comes up, select Advanced System Settings, right hand side.

[image]

**(6)** It helps to have the same username on both computers.  If you do not, you will need to enumerate a Windows 10 user name on the Windows 7 machine (Manage Computer, Users and Groups) so that you can share folder on Windows  using that name.

**(7)** Restart both computers after making these changes.

Now try mapping folders. Map from Windows 10, not from Windows 7.

A couple of notes: (a) you may need to map a folder using the IP Address of Windows 7 and (b) we cannot map USER folders (too secure). So your MAP line might look like:

Net use  Z:  \IPaddressofwindows7\temp where temp holds the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Could you please clarify on step 5, specifically how to check in Windows 10.

Comment: I have done that for you. Depending on the Windows 10 version, right click on My Computer (Computer), select Properties and in the Window that comes up, select Advanced System Settings, right hand side,

Comment: Cool...Thanks a lot for that...and just to clarify on last thing when you say "Map from Windows 10, not from Windows 7", I want to copy data which is on my old Windows 7 laptop to the new Windows 10 laptop. So assume that is also possible ?

Comment: Yes. After all the steps, in Windows 10, Windows Explorer, Map Network Drive and map a folder on the Windows 7 machine. I have done this many times.

Comment: Cool...Thanks...Seems like I am facing some issue with enabling/disabling SMBv2/SMBv1...This is the error I see - 
Set-ItemProperty : Requested registry access is not allowed.
At line:1 char:17

Comment: I added another article. You can also search for Enable SMBv2 on Windows 7

Comment: Ultimately, if you really get stuck you can put the data (documents) you need from Windows 7 on a USB Drive to transfer the information.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help...I have followed all the steps....but for some reason, I am still unable to see the old Windows 7 laptop under my Network from Windows 10 laptop

Comment: Yes,I know pen drive is an option...but want to keep that as the last, since I have a lot of data

Comment: Anything to check related to firewall settings ?

Comment: Try sharing your Drive C: on Windows 7. Give it a name and share it to the user name you have or set up.  On Windows 10, map network drive as follows:  net use z: \\name of win 7\name of folder and authenticate. Firewall is normally automatic

Comment: Hmm...strangely no luck...So just FYI...I now have exactly the same Computer Name for both the laptops...Assume that should be fine

Comment: We cannot share USER folders, so make sure the data on Windows 7 is in a neutral folder like C:\temp.  Copy it there if need be. Same computer so that copy will be fast.  Also you may need to map with the IP address of Windows 7.